# ListView pass data to another ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have two activities with List View's:

Activity A --> ListView person

Activity B --> ListView favouritePerson

In person ListView there is a button i every item of the list

person --> Button likeButton

I would like to add person to favouritePerson list when the like button is clicked. I was trying to achieve this by adding data to singleton and then trying to get it from there, but without success. I have also tried to use SharedPreferences, but could not get it right either. What would be the best approach for this workflow?

I also forget to mention, that I'm populating the first listView by querying the Realm database.

Comment: In activity A. from where you are getting data to fill in listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I would like to add person to favouritePerson list when the like button is clicked
```

To get this, onClick like button, you need to write a query to insert favourite bit in data base against that record. And when you load activity B updated data will be populated. No singleton, sharedpreference or Parcelable is required. This is the best approach. Update database record on the fly and get updated data in Activity B.